# How can I store multiple variable datas in a string/array

Tags: c, input, time.h

I was wondering if there's a way to store multiple variable data in a string. I am trying to store the date, month and year that I am taking from user as an input to store in a single string/array.

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&getDate.dd,&getDate.mm,&getDate.yyyy);
```

Assuming that the value entered above is a valid input, How can I store `getDate.dd`, `getDate.mm`, `getDate.yyyy` in a single string/array in a `DD-MM-YYYY` format?

Comment: if you want a string, store it in a string. What is the question?

Comment: Oh, and if you're asking what format specifier to use, better to re-read a C book.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I store multiple variable values into a single array or list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427465/how-can-i-store-multiple-variable-values-into-a-single-array-or-list)

Comment: @Peter The link you gave is for a Java solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) function to write data to a character string:

```c
//...
char dataString[11]; // Enough space for DD-MM-YYYY plus the required nul-terminator
sprintf(dateString, "%02d-%02d-%04d", getDate.dd, getDate.mm, getDate.yyyy);
```

The `%02d` format specifies that 2 digits should be printed, adding a leading zero if the value is < 10.